# Tableview doesn't show data on ipad with iOS 9.3 version

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am showing the data on tableview. Everything is working fine on iphone and ipad but data is not showing on ipad with version 9.3.

```
import UIKit

class AddPatientViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var explain: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tblViewAddPatient: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mobile: ZWTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var age: ZWTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fullname: ZWTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btnFemale: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnMale: UIButton!

var gender :String = ""
var username :String = ""
var complain :String = ""
var strLabel = UILabel()
var indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
var arrComplain = ["-Check-Up","-Teeth Cleaning","-Peroidonatal","-Dental Fillings","-Prothesis","-Extraction","-Hollywoods Smile","-Childrens's Teeth","-Bleaching"]

var arrManaege = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    explain.delegate = self
    let defaults1 = UserDefaults.standard
    let user = defaults1.object(forKey: "user") as? NSData
    let responseData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: user! as Data) as? ResponseModel

    if responseData != nil {
        if responseData?.profile != nil {
            username = (responseData?.profile[0].userName)!;
            name.text = responseData?.profile[0].userFullName
        }
    }

    mobile.delegate = self
    age.delegate = self
    fullname.delegate = self
    tblViewAddPatient.dataSource = self
    tblViewAddPatient.delegate = self
    let tapFirstGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard(_:)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapFirstGestureRecognizer)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"  // Recognizes enter key in keyboard
    {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == fullname {
        age.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == age {
        mobile.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == mobile {
        mobile.resignFirstResponder()
    } 
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func backClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
   _ =  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func btnFemaleClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    if(btnFemale.isSelected){

    }else{
        btnFemale.isSelected = true
        btnMale.isSelected = false
    }
}

@IBAction func btnMaleClicked(_ sender: Any) {


    if(btnMale.isSelected){

    }else{
        btnFemale.isSelected = false
        btnMale.isSelected = true
    }
}
// Tableview delegates and datasource

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrComplain.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tblViewAddPatient.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddPatientTCC") as! AddPatientTCC
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.lblTitel.text = arrComplain[indexPath.row]

    if (arrManaege[indexPath.row] == "0"){
        cell.btnCheckBox.isSelected = false
    }else{
        cell.btnCheckBox.isSelected = true
    }

    cell.btnCheckBox.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnCheckBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddPatientViewController.btnCheckBoxClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (arrManaege[indexPath.row] == "0"){
        arrManaege[indexPath.row] = "1"
    }else{
        arrManaege[indexPath.row] = "0"
    }
    tblViewAddPatient.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func saveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if fullname.text!.isEmpty {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if age.text!.isEmpty {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if mobile.text!.isEmpty {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if explain.text!.isEmpty {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if btnMale.isSelected == false , btnFemale.isSelected == false {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if arrManaege[0] == "0",arrManaege[1] == "0",arrManaege[2] == "0",arrManaege[3] == "0",arrManaege[4] == "0",arrManaege[5] == "0",arrManaege[6] == "0",arrManaege[7] == "0",arrManaege[8] == "0" {
        showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "All fields are Mandatory");
        return
    }

    if btnFemale.isSelected == true {
        gender = "Female"
    } else {
        gender = "Male"
    }

    complain = arrManaege[0]+arrManaege[1]+arrManaege[2]+arrManaege[3]+arrManaege[4]+arrManaege[5]+arrManaege[6]+arrManaege[7]+arrManaege[8];
    let netowrk = NetworkCall();
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        self.showLoading(title: "Please wait")

    netowrk.addPatient(patientMobile: mobile.text!,patientGender: gender,patientAge: age.text!,patientComplaint: complain,patientExplainComplain: explain.text!,paitentName: fullname.text!,username: username) { responseObject in
        self.hideLoading()
        if responseObject.status == "true" {

            print("Success view controller");

            self.showAlerError(titleText: "Success", messagetext: "Patient Added successfully");
        } else {
            self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: responseObject.message!);
        }
        return
    }
    } else {
        self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "Please check Internet connectivity");
    }
}
func btnCheckBoxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (arrManaege[sender.tag] == "0"){
        arrManaege[sender.tag] = "1"
    }else{
        arrManaege[sender.tag] = "0"
    }
    tblViewAddPatient.reloadData()
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    if textView.text == "Explain your compaint"
    {
        textView.text = ""
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if textView.text == ""
    {
        textView.text = "Explain your compaint"
    }
}


func showLoading(title: String) {

    strLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    indicator.removeFromSuperview()
    effectView.removeFromSuperview()

    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 160, height: 46))
    strLabel.text = title
    strLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.7)

    effectView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - strLabel.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.midY - strLabel.frame.height/2 , width: 160, height: 46)
    effectView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    effectView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    indicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    indicator.startAnimating()

    effectView.addSubview(indicator)
    effectView.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(effectView)
}

func hideLoading() {
    self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
    //indicator.stopAnimating()
}

func showAlerError(titleText:String,messagetext:String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message:
        messagetext, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

I am using swift 3.1 but don't know why it is not showing data on iPad with iOS version 9.3 only. Please help me as I an new to swift. I tried all option but nothing is working for me.

[image]

Comment: do you have separate storyboard for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: @IrshadAhmed Yes.

Comment: You are trying to use unarchiveObject to get(read) userName and userFullName with key "user", but where you have written code to put(save) data with a key "user"?